# How long will it take Google to show rich music snippet cards for my website?

Tags: google-search-console, music, rich-cards

How long does it take for Google to review submission of my expressed interest in Music category for rich cards?

I am serving copyright DRM content through my web site. I successfully got all of my pages indexed. Now I want this beautiful feature called "rich cards" in the search results.

I read [this](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/) guide and already registered my site to Google Search Console.

Comment: That guide says that "Your user’s search intent drives presentation".  It doesn't say that Google reviews sites to make them eligible.